# Вопрос по логике Python и высшмат

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Смотрел лекции по питону и наткнулся на интересный момент

```
-11 // 10 = -2
-11 % 10 = 9
```

Это вообще как?
Почему получается не -1 и -1?

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что если -2 * 10 +9 мы получаем искомое -11.  Вопрос - почему именно -2 и 9, а не -1 и -1 с точки зрения математики.

Comment: Остаток от целочисленного деления всегда неотрицателен.

Comment: Ну есть одна очень хорошая статя которая объясняет как и почему все именно так: https://habr.com/post/421071/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знак остатка зависит от соглашения, принятого в конкретном языке программирования. [Таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0). При этом в любом случае выполняется

```
a = b * Q + R
```

В Python знак остатка должен совпадать со знаком **делителя**, поэтому в данном случае остаток положительный, и целочисленное деление выполняется с округлением к минус бесконечности.

А вот в Паскале знак остатка определяется делимым, и

```
-11 div 9 = -1
-11 mod 9 = -2
```